# No response with a query by ID on Azure DocumentDB

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I'm currently facing very slow/ no response on a collection looking by ID. I have ~ 2 milion of documents in a partitioned collection. If lookup the document using the partitionKey and id the response is immediate

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.partitionKey=123 AND c.id="20566-2"
```

if I try using only the id

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id="20566-2"
```

the response never returns, java client seems freezed and I have the same situation using the Data Explorer from Azure Portal. I tried also looking up by another field that isn't the id or the partitionKey and the response always returns. When I try the select from Java client I always set the flag to enable cross partition query.

The next thing to try is to avoid the character "-" in the ID to test if this character blocks the query (anyway I didn't find anything on the documentation)

Comment: Are you able to run the same query from the portal?

Comment: No the same query from portal doesn't return anything

Comment: Can you add your java code? I can help more with that... Roughly, when you are querying a partitioned table, you must provide a partition key, or turn on cross partition queries, which is off by default because you should be doing this rarely with nosql.

Comment: The problem isn't related to Java code because also from portal the behavior is the same. If I query not using the partition key and not using id the query works, so I think the problem is related to partition and id

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to your Java code. Due to Azure DocumentDB Java SDK wrapped the DocumentDB REST APIs, according to the reference of REST API [`Query Documents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/query-documents), as @DanCiborowski-MSFT said, the header `x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition` explains your issue reason as below.

> **Header**: **x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition**
>   **Required**/**Type**: Optional/Boolean
>   **Description**: If the collection is partitioned, this must be set to True to allow execution across multiple partitions. Queries that filter against a single partition key, or against single-partitioned collections do not need to set the header.

So you need to set `True` to enable cross partition for querying across multiple partitions without a partitionKey in where clause via pass a instance of class [`FeedOption`](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-java/com/microsoft/azure/documentdb/FeedOptions.html) to the method [`queryDocuments`](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-java/com/microsoft/azure/documentdb/DocumentClient.html#queryDocuments-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.FeedOptions-), as below.

```
FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions();
queryOptions.setEnableCrossPartitionQuery(true); // Enable query across multiple partitions
String collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
FeedResponse<Document> queryResults = documentClient.queryDocuments(
    collectionLink,
    "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id='20566-2'", queryOptions);
```

Comment: The issue isn't related to Java code, because the behavior is the same also using the Azure Portal. Anyway I have already used the enableCrossPartitionQuery flag but it doesn't work. Using Azure Portal there isn't the need for this flag because querying without partitionKey but using a field different from id the query works. For example `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.anotherFieldThatIsntPartitionOrId='BLAHBLAHBLAH'` works

Comment: @FedericoPaparoni Please try to use Fiddler to catch the API call to inspect what happended.

Comment: Using something like Fiddler I can see that when I make the blocking call the server returns a JSON Object like this `{"_rid":"vFwmAPVJtgA=","Documents":[{"id":"1697-1","_self":"dbs\/vFwmAA==\/colls\/vFwmAPVJtgA=\/docs\/vFwmAPVJtgADAAAAAAAAAA==\/","_rid":"vFwmAPVJtgADAAAAAAAAAA==","_ts":1496737515,"_partitionKeyValue":91}],"_count":1}` but the browser anyway doesn't display anything from Azure Portal